# signOut() method not working properly. Firebase

Tags: firebase, kotlin, firebase-authentication

I have an authorized user, and trying to sign him out after click the button. But after signOut method, the current user not null. And after reopen app user automatically logged in.

The sign in method is
`signInWithEmailAndPassword`

That what im get from log

```
D/FirebaseAuth: Notifying auth state listeners about a sign-out event.
D/FirebaseAuth: Notifying id token listeners about a sign-out event.
```

```kotlin
        binding.signOut.setOnClickListener {
            FirebaseAuth.getInstance().signOut()
            System.exit(0)
        }
```

Answer (score 0):

You are using Java code for SignOut. Try this instead `Firebase.auth.signOut()`.

Comment: still not working. current user is not null

Comment: Which signIn method are you using?

Comment: createUserWWithEmailAndPassword

Answer (score 0):

The problem was solved by a remove `System.exit(0)`. I think signOut event is async, and cannot be able to do while system.exit shutting down app